# <ul><li> selection populate separate <div>

Tags: jquery

I am trying to populate a separate `<div>` element based on a menu selection from one `<div>`.  The content to be displayed will be hidden until the `<li><a>` is selected from the vertical menu.

I have read how to do this with jQuery but it doesn't seem to be working.

I am not looking for a "cut/paste" answer, just a point in the right direction.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ateamhammer/scosck2c/)

Comment: You need to share the code in the question along with the demo link

Comment: I didnot get what you exactly want

Comment: @ateamhammer buddy onclick <li> of first div, you want it to be added on second div?? Can you explain what is your requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display content in your right div according your left panel on click, you can do it like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.left ul li a').click(function(e)  {
    e.preventDefault();
    $($(this).attr('href')).show().siblings().hide();
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.left {
 padding: 0;
 left: 10%;
 width: 33.3%;
 position: absolute;
 height: 500px;
 color: white;
 border: thin solid #000;
}

#right {
 padding: 0;
 right: 10%;
 width: 33.3%;
 position: absolute;
 height: 500px;
 color: white;
 border: thin solid #000;
}

.vertical {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width:100%;
 list-style:none;
 opacity:1;
 z-index:1;
}

ul.vertical {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border: .5px solid #555;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

li.vertical {
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
}

li.vertical:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}

li.vertical a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 0 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
 
}

li.vertical a:hover {
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
}

li.vertical.active a {
    background: red;
}

.tab {
    display:none;
}

.tab.active {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left" style="top:25%; background-color: #333; opacity:.6;">
  <ul class="vertical">
        <li class="vertical active"><a href="#tab1">Link 1</a></li>
        <li class="vertical"><a href="#tab2">Link 2</a></li>
        <li class="vertical"><a href="#tab3">Link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="right" style="top:25%; background-color: #333; opacity:.6;">
  <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
      <p>Content 1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab">
      <p>Content 2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tab3" class="tab">
      <p>Content 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that is exactly what I was looking for!  Thank you.